# Pushing data to JSON object javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to push this object to a JSON array

```
var obj =  {'x':21,'y':32,'z':43};
```

Since my JSON key:value comes dynamically , I cant access using keys , so i used the loop method .

```
var str = {xA : []}; //declared a JSON array

for (var key in obj) {

    alert(' name=' + key + ' value=' + obj[key]);

     str.xA.push({
         key :   obj[key]
     })
}
```

When i alert the values I am getting the keys and values properly, but when I am pushing it to the array my key is always coming as 'key' instead of the actual key like x, y,z as in the code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a JavaScript object literal, NOT JSON.

Comment: Please, don't use the word "JSON", there's no JSON at all here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The literal notation does not allow expressions for keys. You need to create the object first and then use the bracket notation instead:

```
var tmp = {};
tmp[key] = obj[key];
str.xA.push(tmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `[]` notation, otherwise always the key name will be `key` and not the value of the key.

```
 str.xA.push({
     key :   obj[key]
 })
```

to

```
   var tmp= {};
   tmp[key] = obj[key]
   str.xA.push(tmp)
```